# can two not equivalent covering maps be homotopic

Tags: algebraic-topology

Let $(Y,p_1)$ , $(Y,p_2)$ be two covering spaces of topological space $X$.
If $(Y,p_1)$ and $(Y,p_2)$ are NOT equivalent can $p_1$ and $p_2$ be homotopic maps?

Comment: For example let $X=Y=S^1$  and $m, n$ integers and $p_1:Y \rightarrow X$ $p_1(z)=z^n$,$p_2:Y \rightarrow X$ $p_2(z)=z^m$. Then $p_1$ and $p_2$ are covering maps and $(p_1)_*$ is isomorphic to $n\mathbb{Z}$ and $(p_2)_*$ is isomorphic to $m\mathbb{Z}$.
I would like to prove that p_1 and p_2 are not homotopic.

Answer (score 0):

If $X$ is path connected, locally path connected, and has a universal covering space, then if $Y$ is connected they must be equivalent because $(p_1)_*(\pi_1(Y))=(p_2)_*(\pi_2(Y))\subset\pi_1(X)$.  This can be extended to $X$ and $Y$ not being path connected.

If $X$ is not locally path connected, it might be possible to find homeomorphic covers which are not equivalent, but I'm unable to supply an example of this.

Comment: I don't understand why would $(p_1)_*(\pi (Y))=(p_2)_*(\pi (Y))$ be true?

Comment: If $p_1$ and $p_2$ are homotopic, then $(p_1)_*=(p_2)_*$.